# symfony VarDumper show file and line

Tags: symfony, var-dump

When using the VarDumper function dump() in a symfony project the file and line of  where dump() was called is shown.

When using the VarDumper component standalone file and line is not shown.

I guess in Symfony it's somewhere configured in the DebugBundle.

Where does this happen exactly and how can I achieve this with the standalone component?

**Update:**
I issued a ticket https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24852
and this shows the feature is indeed not included in the component but probably planned for the next releases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this component:
https://github.com/morrislaptop/var-dumper-with-context

results:
https://www.screencast.com/t/d7IzVtcO

Comment: Thanks, that package looks good and shows how to achieve this.